# Possible to get a listing of all folder permissions/access on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, file-permissions

We are migrating one of our legacy servers at work to a new data center (different domain, etc...).  This server has a folder with MANY nested folders inside of it.  Each of the nested folders may have different explicit permissions granted to different users.  There are hundreds of folders.

Is there a way I can get all the permissions in a report using PowerShell or something similar for all the folders & nested folders?  Im looking for an easy-as-possible way to replicate the folder permissions or get some output where I can manually recreate it?

Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason you want to manually recreate folder permissions and not use ADMT? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8377

Comment: I had not heard of ADMT before.  Can it be selective with what it replicates (i.e. just this one folder and all it's children)?

Comment: IIRC, you can just copy what folders you want over. ADMT will take care of the security translation. This way you're not manually recreating users, groups and permissions.

Comment: Very cool.  Ill have to read into it because we are coming from a different domain the user IDs may not match precisely but it's good to know this tool exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [blog post](http://jfrmilner.wordpress.com/2011/05/01/audit-ntfs-permissions-powershell-script/) on how to audit NTFS Permissions with PowerShell. It will export all the info out into a CSV.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using [this one](http://poshcode.org/1721), very similar but I only needed it for 1 folder on 1 server.